# VBA - Como faço para aplicar uma fórmula em células filtradas? Como identificar a primeira celula e a última para utilizar o Autofill?

Tags: vba, excel-vba, macro

Tenho uma tabela que preciso filtrar a coluna B e em seguida aplicar uma fórmula.
Porém, não consigo inserir na fórmula o valor da **linha** da primeira célula vísivel para arrastar a fórmula. Podem me ajudar? Segue o código que estou tentando:

```
Dim n As Integer
n = Range("B1").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("B2").Offset(1, 0).Activate
Do Until Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Hidden = False
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(MID(RC[-1],SEARCH(""#"",RC[-1],1),SEARCH(""#"",RC[-1],SEARCH(""#"",RC[-1],1)+1)),CONCAT(""Seu pedido foi "",""*"",RC[6],""*"","". Para mais informações, solicite atendimento com nossa equipe.""))"
Range("B2").Offset(1, 0).Select
   
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B210" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
```

Comment: 1ualbetapa exatamente você não consegue realizar? E em qual momento?

Comment: Olá! Então consigo localizar a primeira celula e colocar a fórmula nela, porém não consigo arrastar para as outras células filtradas. Na fórmula onde está "B210", muda conforme os filtros, precisava mudar isso pq em outro relatório a primeira celula visivel pode ser B208, por exemplo.